# XFCE Websites Textarea cols wrong in different browsers

Tags: debian, xfce4

I just noticed that the cols option on websites/textareas doesn't really apply on my laptop with debian 12. I double checked with an virtual machine that has debian 11 installed and there everything works as expected.

Firefox (VM):
[image: Screenshot Firefox (VM)]

Firefox (local):
[image: Screenshot Firefox (local)]

Chromium (local):
[image: Screenshot Chromium (local)]